# how to select a specific condition in table from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a specific condition based on the result from another table that has a key between them I tried to like an equal but it fails to give results

> I am using it to android so result show on android and I click on menu_id on android

The key between the two tables is menu_id, menu_id in load options primary and in load menu index

---

### **load options**

```
 <?php
  $query = "SELECT * FROM menu";
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,query);
  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  array_push($result, array(
  'menu_id' => $row[0],
  'menu_name' =>$row[1],
  'menu_img' =>$row[2] ));
  }
  echo json_encode($result);
  mysqli_close($conn);
  }
  ?>
```

---

**load menu

---

```
<?php

  $query = "SELECT * FROM menulist ORDER BY food_name ASC";
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,query);
  $result = array();
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
  array_push($result, array(
  'food_id' => $row[0],
  'menu_id' =>$row[1],
  'food_name' =>$row[2],
  'food_description' =>$row[2],
  'food_img' =>$row[2],));
  }
  echo json_encode($result);
  mysqli_close($conn);
  }
?>
```

---

I tired menu_id == menu_id and menu_id like :menu_id but i get no result

Comment: Where did you try ```menu_id == menu_id```? I don't see anywhere in your code where that would happen. Why not join the two tables in your SQL statement?

Comment: i posted SELECT * FROM menulist ORDER BY food_name ASCas its the only only one that is work but it only shows me all results

Comment: @SloanThrasher and how can i do the inner join with key reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to join the two tables with the condition on the `menu_id` field.
Take look at [joins](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) and [sql aliases](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

```
// assign foodname from your $_GET[‘food’] or $_POST[‘food’] parameter
$foodname = $_GET[‘food’];
$query = "SELECT ML.* 
          FROM menulist ML
          INNER JOIN menu M 
          ON ML.menu_id = M.menu_id
WHERE ML.foodname = ‘$foodname’
          ORDER BY ML.food_name ASC";
```

Comment: it shows all result .. thats why im confused of how to use innerJoin with no isset or session defined

Comment: @NaelMahrous Yes, it shows all results. Do you have a particular menu_id or condition to apply? Let me know the condition

Comment: yes, i am trying to get for example pizza menu from menu list to show when i press pizza from menu